# Rendering Youtube Video in a WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, parsing, youtube, wysiwyg

I am creating a custom WYSIWYG from scratch using JavaScript. All of it is working fine (like inserting pictures), but when I click on submit and the content gets added to my database, the YouTube video gets inserted like this:

`<div><br></div><div><br><div><br></div></div>`

I have created a JavaScript file that the WYSIWYG parses to:

```
function iImage(){
    var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image location', '');
    if (imgSrc != null){
        richTextField.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc);
    }
}
function iVideo(){
    var urlPrompt = prompt("Enter Youtube Url:", "http://");
    var urlReplace = urlPrompt.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
    var embed = '<iframe src="'+urlReplace+'" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" frameborder="0" height="390">';
    if($.browser.msie){
        richTextField.document.createRange().pasteHTML(embed);
    }else{
        richTextField.document.execCommand("Inserthtml", false, embed);
    }
}
function submit_form(){
    var theForm = document.getElementById("blogForm");
    theForm.elements["blogbody"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

You can see that my `iImage` function works, but not my `iVideo`.

Can anyone help?

Just to let you know i have edited my script to this...

```
function iVideo(){
    var urlPrompt = prompt("Enter Youtube Url:", "http://");
    var urlReplace = urlPrompt.replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/");
    var embed = '<iframe src="'+urlReplace+'" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" frameborder="0" height="390"></iframe>';
    if($.browser.msie){
        richTextField.document.createRange().pasteHTML(embed);
    }else{
        richTextField.document.execCommand("Inserthtml", false, embed);
    }
}
```

but still no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it. This is the code below

```
function iVideo(){
    var urlPrompt = prompt("Enter Youtube Url:", "http://");
    var urlReplace = urlPrompt.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
    var embed = '<iframe title="YouTube video player" src="'+urlReplace+'" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" frameborder="0" height="390">';
    if(embed != null){
        richTextField.document.execCommand("Inserthtml", false, embed);`
    }
}
```

It working on my sites right now.

Comment: please format your text with pretty printing and [language highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) to make it easier for people who read your post. Thanks for the community!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate
The reason you don't see a Youtube.com is because it will be added by you upon uploading. In the form where you write content you intend to upload to your site, You are to click on a Add Video link which will tricker off the first line in the code to popup a window requesting you to submit your Youtube video link, which looks something like http://youtube.com/theVideoLink. The link you add will then be placed where you have `src="'+urlReplace+'"` that is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am a begginner at javascript, but I don't see anywhere were it adds youtube.com to it, all I see is the watch?v=.
As I said, a beginners opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to first try a hardcoded/static version like below first?
-  might be just syntax or one of your variables not set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function iVideo(){
      var youtubeiframe='<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AsbagZvkrbo" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
      richTextField.document.execCommand ("insertHTML", false, youtubeiframe);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Have tried that as well! still just inserting empty div taks into my database!

Comment: can you take the db insert out of the picture next, and see if this code completes the exec command to the browser ? .. does it render the iframe ?